# SharePoint 2013 with Google Chrome Version 29 is not working well

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-addin, browser-compatibility

I am facing the following problems when accessing SharePoint 2013 using google chrome Version 29.0.1547.66 m:-

1. On an Announcement App part I will get the following error:-

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'RenderHeader' of undefinedTypeError:
>   Cannot call method 'RenderField' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot call
>   method 'RenderField' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot call method
>   'RenderField' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot call method 'RenderField'
>   of undefinedTypeError: Cannot call method 'RenderField' of undefined

And when I click on ctrl +F5 the error will disappear for the first refresh and then it will appear again , and so on.

2. When I click on a document library list, I will get the following error:-

> ReferenceError: Strings is not definedTypeError: Cannot call method
>   'RenderField' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot call method 'RenderField'
>   of undefinedTypeError: Cannot call method 'RenderField' of
>   undefinedTypeError: Cannot call method 'RenderField' of
>   undefinedTypeError: Cannot call method 'RenderField' of
>   undefinedTypeError: Cannot call method 'RenderField' of
>   undefinedTypeError: Cannot call method 'RenderField' of
>   undefinedTypeError: Cannot call method 'RenderField' of
>   undefinedTypeError: Cannot call method 'RenderField' of
>   undefinedTypeError: Cannot call method 'RenderField' of undefined

And same as the announcement App part refreshing the page will remove the error temporarily.

3. I have the following code inside a code snippet to display  a dialog box :-

> http://192.168.8.221/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=726',1000,1000);"
>   unselectable="on">Camera One

But the dialog will be display with wrong width and height.

Baring in mind that I have never faced these issues on IE or in Firefox ? so can anyone advice on what might be causing these errors and bugs ?

Below is an image containing the three problems :-
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the app without the code snippet? you said that this page with the app works in IE and Firefox? Also You might add the IP address in the code snippet to your exception settings in Chrome for Popups etc.  Chrome might be blocking it.

Comment: i do not think chrome is blocking anything, as if i do a hard refresh the APP will work for one time till i click on the page again. regarding the pop-up it will be displayed but with wrong width and height , since if i use the scroll inside the dialog box i can see its content, which means that chrome did not block it , but it did not apply the right width and height .

Comment: You didn't mention if you tried without the code snippet.  Have you tried to view a page with just the basic announcement app?  I am running Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m and have no problems with announcements or any other OOTB App Part.  I would focus on the custom elements in your configuration and see if there is some incompatibility you can identify.  Possibly a plugin in Chrome?

Comment: my code sniipet was a simple javascript timer to display the date and time, and i have removed it but the problem still the same. i am not sure what type of problem it is . as when you u first visit the page the error occur , doing a refresh will remove it, if not do another hard refresh the error will disappear. then if i visit the page again after navigation to other pages, the error will occur, i do a refresh it will disappear !!!!. and i have never faced this issue on IE or fireofx !!!

Comment: i also added three extensions for chrome : fix SharePoint  Scrolling 0.2 & IE Tab & sharePoint Fix .1.5. but none of these extensions solve the problem . any advice ?